# CSS file not loading for page with multiple arguments

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

I am working with google app engine for a class, and while working on a project, I came across something strange that I can't figure out. When I load a site with multiple arguments, such as www.something.com/something/1, the css file doesn't affect the page. It does this even if I copy and paste the exact code from another working html file. I am guessing it has to do with the multiple arguments and maybe me not defining something in the app.yaml file, but I am not sure really. Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you need any code, I didn't figure it would be useful in this case.

WWaldo

Edit:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>Google App Engine</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/page.css"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not showing any code so it's hard to tell for sure, but my guess is that you are using relative references to your CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

these will break when you're in a different directory. `/something/1` will be interpreted by the browser as a different directory, so it will search for

```
/something/1/styles.css
```

the best solution is usually to use absolute paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/styles.css">
```

Comment: I edited the original post with my <head>, let me see if putting the / makes a difference

Comment: @WWaldo yup, it definitely will.